# Subversion setup for lone programmer on separate machines

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, installation, dropbox

I'm just getting started with subversion. I have web applications which I need to be able to work on from both my home and office computers. I've installed CollabNet SVN Edge server on my home machine, and TortoiseSVN on both my home and office machines. I've also setup a free account with Assemblia, a free subversion hosting service and created some repositories for my projects. And I'm not sure if Assemblia is the tool I need to check-out / commit files from two separate computers. So figuring out how to setup my home and office machines has my head spinning. Do I even need to install CollabNet on both computers, or will that cause file syncing confusion? I understand that TortoiseSVN is the locally-installed tool to interact with repositories and have been able to use it with Assemblia. I've also read that I need to install Apache in order to use CollabNet SVN. I do have WAMP server on both computers, but am going to be working with IIS 7 & MySQL for installations of CMS's like Wordpress and Joomla. I've also read the arguments for and against using Dropbox as a go-between for subversion access across multiple computers, and am further perplexed. So any advice from stand-alone PHP / MySQL developers on best practices for subversion between two computers would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: I should mention that the projects I'm working on are currently local installations using WAMP on my two computers. I am not able as of yet to install software like CollabNet Server on my server at work due to firewall issues and general idiocy / lack of trust from my campus IT department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use Assembla then you don't need to install any additional SVN servers. Assembla *is* the SVN server, and all you  need on your computers is TortoiseSVN (or any other SVN *client*)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install apache or WAMP, you need that if you want to host your own server. TortoiseSVN is a svn client, this is what you need to check out and commit files.

If you like working from the command line, you can download the subversion command line client for windows [here](http://www.open.collab.net/servlets/OCNDirector?id=CSVN1.6.15WINC)

Comment: Thanks to all. Augusto: Can I ask a follow-up question? If I setup Wordpress or Joomla on my home PC using WAMP for server-side needs (PHP, MySQL). Then I want to transfer/migrate my home installation to my work computer to continue working on it. I can see how TortoiseSVN and Assembla could help me do this. But why wouldn't I need to install WAMP or Apache on either of my computers? Is that if I choose to skip using CollabNet Server? I have some hosted web space, but I checked and they don't permit subversion which is why I went with Assemblia. Thanks for any clarification you can provide.

Comment: In your case you'll need to install WAMP. I thought you wanted to install WAMP in order to add the subversion mod to apache, and thus convert that installation into an subversion server. It's a bit confusing since the subversion server runs on top of Apache :).

Answer (score 0):

For simple Subversion, you just need two client PCs and a server that is possibly 24/7 online. One of the two computers, especially if a work computer, may act as the server.

You don't require particular additional ooftware if you have Assemblia: they will provide you with repository URL that you can use in the clients, so no need for server.